# Contract-helper url for mainnet: to get delegation info of specific account id

Tags: nearprotocol

I want to get delegation information(validators, amount) of specific account id. This link, https://near-contract-helper.onrender.com/staking-deposits/kms.testnet, seems like for testnet because I could find delegation information of my testnet account.

however, I couldn’t get results with my mainnet account (I delegated 1.36NEAR for sure): https://near-contract-helper.onrender.com/staking-deposits/kwklly.near

So I’m wondering if there’s any other url for mainnet to get delegation information of specific account id.

++ there's a problem in testnet contract-helper: `FAILED TXS are shown either`.
I failed to delegate to `@dsrvlabs.poolv1.near`, but I could see it with contract-helper.

Tx receipt: https://explorer.testnet.near.org/transactions/7LFsSHGQ5WgcVDWwgrwYjD38umb5QHrdYsVMFjDadngH

contract-helper:
https://near-contract-helper.onrender.com/staking-deposits/kms.testnet

Answer (score 2):

The Contract Helper at that address is configured to query `testnet` instead of `mainnet`, it can't work on both. The correct URL is `https://helper.mainnet.near.org/`

However, I was able to retrieve the same information with [Near-CLI](https://github.com/near/near-cli), using the following command:

`near view dsrvlabs.poolv1.near get_account '{"account_id": "kwklly.near"}'`

The result is:

```
$ near view dsrvlabs.poolv1.near get_account '{"account_id": "kwklly.near"}'
View call: dsrvlabs.poolv1.near.get_account({"account_id": "kwklly.near"})
{
  account_id: 'kwklly.near',
  unstaked_balance: '1',
  staked_balance: '1370597785335174013176165',
  can_withdraw: true
}
```

This information can be retrieved even without Near-CLI or the contract helper, querying a NEAR node running inside your own network. An example in cURL for the very same call is:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://rpc.mainnet.near.org/' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "query",
    "params": {
        "request_type": "call_function",
        "finality": "final",
        "account_id": "dsrvlabs.poolv1.near",
        "method_name": "get_account",
        "args_base64": "eyJhY2NvdW50X2lkIjogImt3a2xseS5uZWFyIn0="
    },
    "id": "dontcare"
}'
```

The expected result should be:

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "result": {
        "block_hash": "5MCrRZAgYzFdYMpHXeQJ25DjrRVFQ1KVgyy8qYTvUhZi",
        "block_height": 44877555,
        "logs": [],
        "result": [
            123,
            34,
            97,
            99,
            99,
            111,
            117,
            110,
            116,
            95,
            105,
            100,
            34,
            58,
            34,
            107,
            119,
            107,
            108,
            108,
            121,
            46,
            110,
            101,
            97,
            114,
            34,
            44,
            34,
            117,
            110,
            115,
            116,
            97,
            107,
            101,
            100,
            95,
            98,
            97,
            108,
            97,
            110,
            99,
            101,
            34,
            58,
            34,
            49,
            34,
            44,
            34,
            115,
            116,
            97,
            107,
            101,
            100,
            95,
            98,
            97,
            108,
            97,
            110,
            99,
            101,
            34,
            58,
            34,
            49,
            51,
            55,
            48,
            53,
            57,
            55,
            55,
            56,
            53,
            51,
            51,
            53,
            49,
            55,
            52,
            48,
            49,
            51,
            49,
            55,
            54,
            49,
            54,
            53,
            34,
            44,
            34,
            99,
            97,
            110,
            95,
            119,
            105,
            116,
            104,
            100,
            114,
            97,
            119,
            34,
            58,
            116,
            114,
            117,
            101,125
        ]
    },
    "id": "dontcare"
}
```

Three important elements to know if you build your own parser:

1. the argument is base64 encoded, such that `{"account_id": "kwklly.near"}` from Near-cli becomes `"args_base64": "eyJhY2NvdW50X2lkIjogImt3a2xseS5uZWFyIn0="`
2. the result is an ascii array, such that `123` is `{` and the sequence `123 34 97 99 99 111 117 110 116 95 105 100 34 58` is the beginning of the result `{"account_id":`
3. you can POST the same query to your local node (even the IP address), changing `https://rpc.mainnet.near.org/` with `http://10.0.0.10:3030/`